# Widows 10 UWP - creating pack in debug/release mode - differences

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp, windows-10-universal

I've created simple Windows 10 UWP app. When I'm creating pack in debug mode and install it, everything is alright. But when I run it in Release mode, It fails.

I assume the problem is with my sqlite database. Because when I run it in debug mode the database file is copied to local folder and has his size (17KB). But when I run it in release mode, the size of file is 0 KB.

I have set my database file to:

```
"Build action: Content"  
"Copy to Output folder: Always"
```

What could be a problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. The setting of your database file and the code you've posted are right. If you still have the problem then please share a [mcve] so that we can reproduce it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggestions. I did it (minimize my project) and miracle. This function to check database works in release mode too. But still doesn't know why it doesn't work in whole project. Did you try build my project or You only checked code?

Comment: Sorry, It seems not working. My mistake. I've checked with already created file in local folder. That I thought it works. 
So I minimalized project. Problem is with 2 function.  On 'root' page I execute checkDataBaseConnection() to create database file if not exist. When I debug, I don't know why after calling GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri) the app moves me to LoadChartContents() function, but then, the database is not created yet, so error appears.This behaviour not appear in debug mode.
[link]https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5ZmP3NVyVJkTnNVc19LYmthNTQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your latest minimized project. The problem here is that the `checkDataBaseConnection` method is a an async method and in your code you didn't wait for it to complete. So it's possible that when `LoadChartContents` method is executed, the database file has not been copied to LocalFolder. Thus, an error will occur in `LoadChartContents` method.

To solve this problem, I'd suggest you wait for the `checkDataBaseConnection` method and navigate to "main" page only when the database exists.

For example, we can change `checkDataBaseConnection` method like following:

```
public static async Task<bool> checkDataBaseConnection()
{
    if (null == await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.TryGetItemAsync("sale.db"))
    {
        StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("sale.db");
        await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "sale.db", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    }

    return true;
}
```

And in "root" page, take advantage of [OnNavigatedTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227508) method like:

```
public root()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    PassedData.passSplit = MySplitView;

    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
}

protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var result = await myDatabase.checkDataBaseConnection();
    if (result)
    {
        MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(main1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I didn't know that I can easy debug in release mode. So I know now where is the problem

I have this piece of code in function which check database:

var uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///sale.db");
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);

Application crash on GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(). In debug mode it'works fine.

Comment: I am having same sort of issue where in store mode the app cnt find the file in assets folder, i cnt reproduce when debugging in release mode, did u find the solution? I am also using GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is linked to properties of your Database file.

Try next steps:

1. On Visual Studio right click on your Database file in Solution
   Explorer and select last item called "Properties"
2. Check 2 properties `"Build Action"` and `"Copy to Output Directory"`.
   Based on your requirements - you can configure this two properties
   as you want.
3. I think configuration with:
   `"Build Action" = "Content"` 
   and
   `"Copy to Output Directory" = "Copy always"` 
   should resolve your situation.

[image: Example]

For more details you can check [file properties on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0c6xyb66(v=vs.100).aspx)

Hope it will help you.

### **UPD:**

I noticed that you already applied such actions. I think you have also a problem with access to file.

Try to use next code to access to your file:

```
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "sale.db"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it's still doesnt'work. I send my whole project with database. I made this in VS 2015 (target version: build 10240):
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5ZmP3NVyVJkd1ZBeHhpaDNlZkU

Part where the error appears is in 'myDatabase.cs'